# Prove 1-Norm is a Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I am just curious how you would simply prove that a 1-norm is a norm. Step-by-step would be very helpful. Proofs are not my strong point. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just checked the three necessity condition every norm has to satisfy? If yes, where did you get stuck? If no, try it and show us your progress. Also please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $(v_k)_{k=0}^{n-1}$. Let $x = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k v_k$. Define the $1$-norm to be
$$ \lVert x \rVert_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k|
$$

Identity of indiscernible: If $x = 0$, then $a_k = 0$ for all $k$, so $\lVert x \rVert_1 = 0$. Conversely, if $\lVert x \rVert_1 = 0$, by the nonnegativity of absolute value, $|a_k| = 0$ for all $k$. Hence $a_k = 0$ and $x = 0$.

Triangle inequality: Let $y = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k v_k$. Then
$$ \lVert x + y \rVert_1
= \lVert \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a_k + b_k) v_k \rVert_1
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k + b_k|
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k| + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |b_k|
= \lVert x \rVert_1 + \lVert y \rVert_1
$$

Homogeneity: Let $\lambda$ be a scalar.
$$ \lVert \lambda x \rVert_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |\lambda a_k| = |\lambda| \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k| = |\lambda| \lVert x\rVert_1
$$

Comment: That was incredibly fast!! Thanks Henry W. This answered my question perfectly.